# Is intersection of two surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$ always a complete intersection?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, curves, projective-varieties

I have two surfaces $A,B \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ generated by two homogenous polynomials $f, g$. I want to know when their intersection $A \cap B$ is a complete intersection. $V \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ with $\dim V = r$ is a complete intersection, if its ideal $I$ has $n - r$ generators.

In my case as $A = Z(f)$ and $B = Z(g)$, we also get $ C: = A \cap B = Z(f) \cap Z(g) = Z(f, g)$. That means if $I(Z(f, g)) = \sqrt{\langle f, g \rangle} = \langle F, G \rangle$ for some homogenous $F, G$ and $\dim C = 1$ (meaning $C$ is a curve), then $C$ is a complete intersection, right? Wouldn't that imply that if $C$ happen to be irreducible, then $C$ is automatically a complete intersection?

But I found in Hartshorne (I, Ex. 2.17) that a twisted cubic is not a complete intersection, but a set theoretic intersection, meaning that twisted cubic is exactly $Z(f) \cap Z(g)$. Where does my reasoning fail exactly? Maybe $ Z(f) \cap Z(g) = Z(f, g)$ is suspicious, but I don't see how.

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean by "distinct" exactly and how does it differ from "two surfaces don't have any irreducible component in common"?

Comment: And I also edited my post, because in this exercise Hartshorne explicitly says explicitly that twisted cubic is a set theoretic intersection, but not a complete intersection in the above sense

Comment: About the distinction between complete intersection and set-theoretic complete intersection: let me retract my first statement, which is true under some interpretation but not helpful in this context. Anyway, if I understand your argument correctly, the flaw is in the step $\sqrt{<f,g>}=<F,G>$. Why should such $F$ and $G$ exist? (Indeed, they don't always, as the twisted cubic example shows.)

Comment: $\sqrt{\langle f, g \rangle} \subset K[X_0, ..., X_n ]$ is a homogenous ideal of a Noetherian ring, hence it should be generated by finitely many homogenous $f_1, ..., f_r \in  K[X_0, ..., X_n ]$, right? Oh, I see, $r$ isn't nesessary two. This appears to be the problem